# send data to a different controller after login in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have a Login.html page:

```
<form class="form" ng-submit="submit()">
  <label for="id">id:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id" ng-model="id">
  <label for="pwd">pass:</label>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" ng-model="password">
  <button type="submit" id="submitSection">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

after i click the submit button i go to the controller and get the data from the api server.

if the id and password are OK i want to go to my index.html and send the response the i get in the Login controller to the index controller

this is my Login controller:

```
var app = angular.module("fastFly", []);
app.controller("Login", function ($scope, $http, $window) {
var scope = $scope;
$scope.submit = function () {
    // alert($scope.password);
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/users/' + $scope.id + '/' + $scope.password)
           .success(function (response) {
               if (response == null)
               {
                   swal("ERROR","wrong user name or password", "error");
               }
               else
               {
                   console.log(response);                       
               }
           });
  });
```

how can i send the response to the index controller?

thanks!

Comment: you can use a service to store your login data and use it from any controller

Comment: you have an example?

Comment: check my answer

Comment: What's your routing solution? E.g. `ui-router`, `ngRoute`...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use a service to store your login data and use it from any controller

Eg:

```
var app = angular.module("fastFly", []);

app.controller("Login", function($scope, $http, $window, loginService) {
    var scope = $scope;
    $scope.submit = function() {
        // alert($scope.password);
        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/users/' + $scope.id + '/' + $scope.password)
            .success(function(response) {
                if (response == null) {
                    swal("ERROR", "wrong user name or password", "error");
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                    loginService.setData(response)
                }
            });
    });
});

app.controller("other", function($scope, loginService) {
    $scope.loginData = loginService.getData();
});

app.service("loginService", function() {
    var loginData = null;

    this.getData = function() {
        return loginData;
    }

    this.setData = function(data) {
        loginData = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: when i call the getData function from the index.html the loginData is null because when the index.html is loal he also load the service.js and then the "var loginData = null;" erase the response

Answer (score 2):

you can use **$rootScope** for store login data and use to another controller

Or- you can use $localstorage to Store login data and use to another controller or anywhere

```
    $localStorage.LocalMessage = "value";
```

Or-

```
    var app = angular.module("fastFly", []);

    app.controller("Login", function($scope, $http, $window, loginService) {
        var scope = $scope;
        $scope.submit = function() {
            // alert($scope.password);
            $http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/users/' + $scope.id + '/' + $scope.password)
                .success(function(response) {
                    if (response == null) {
                        swal("ERROR", "wrong user name or password", "error");
                    } else {
                        console.log(response);
                        loginService.setData(response)
                    }
                });
        });
    });

    app.controller("other", function($scope, loginService) {
        $scope.loginData = loginService.getData();
    });

    app.service("loginService", function() {
        var loginData = null;

        this.getData = function() {
            return loginData;
        }

        this.setData = function(data) {
            loginData = data;
        }
    });
```

Comment: where should i put the  $localStorage.LocalMessage = "value";  ?

Comment: when your response give success value

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) for that